# Fatal Error: unidentified method mysqli:fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am writing a time clock program and I am running into an error that I can not seem to find in the code. After looking over the code, I do not find an error where it says there is one. I did a check on PHP Code Checker too and it did not find one. Here is the code that I am using. I have modified the sensitive information. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it. I was following the example on the 3rd answer here:
[display data from SQL database into php/ html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251095/display-data-from-sql-database-into-php-html-table)

Here is the output:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_array() in path to file on line 31
>
> Punch ID  Time    Punch Type  Group   Department  Notes
> and the code

```
<head>
    <title>View My Punches</title>
    <body bgcolor="#9966FF">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="path to favicon"/>
</head>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'host');


$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($link->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Could not connect: ' .connect_error());
}
$userid_value = $_POST['userid'];
$table = "tc_".$userid_value;
$checkusersql = "SELECT * FROM tc_users WHERE userid = '$userid_value'";
$usercheck = $link->query($checkusersql);
$punchessql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$result = $link->query($punchessql);
if ($usercheck->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, " . $userid_value . " is not a valid user ID. Please try again.";
}else {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>Punch ID</td><td>Time</td><td>Punch Type</td><td>Group</td><td>Department</td><td>Notes</td></tr>";
    while ($row = $link->fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['time'] . "</td></tr>" . $row['punchtype'] . "</td><td>" . $row['groupname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dept'] . "</td><td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td><td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

Comment: I suggest you have a read of this in regards to making your queries safe from SQL injection ~ http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. You also have a potential error in your use of the undefined function `connect_error()`. You probably meant to use `$link->connect_error`. Also, a table per user? That's pretty bad schema design

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it is a bad schema design but I just thought that it would be easiest in the long run as we hope to be able to pull reports between punches and all that stuff, so to make it easier to do the math later, we decided to do it that way. Thank you for the comment on the connect error though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$link->fetch_array($result)` use [`$result->fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Valid optional `mysqli_result::fetch_array()` parameters are `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM` or `MYSQLI_BOTH` (default) to determine if the values array should return in associative or numeric format.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$result` instead of `$link`.

Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/mysqli) before asking questions. And read the error message as well. It took me 5 seconds to figure out what the problem was, which tells me that you should have been able to figure it out yourself.