# Displaying table contents with php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to display table data using PHP however for an unknown reason the result I am getting is not what I expected. I am aiming to display a table with the data from the database inside it however I am instead seeing the table with the variable names inside but no data, and above the table I see the word `echo` repeated. The code I am using is as follows;

```
<?php
//connect to database
mysql_connect('mysqlhost3', '40099609', 'ou2wareyido');
mysql_select_db('40099609'); 

$sql="SELECT * FROM gig";

$records=mysql_query($sql);


?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Gig Data </title>
</head>

<body>

<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th> ID </th>
<th> Start Time </th>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Venue </th>
<th> Act </th>
<th> Img </th>


</tr>
<?php
while ($employee=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
echo "<tr>";

echo"<td>".$id['ID']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$start['Start Time']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$sname['Name']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$venue['Venue']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$act['Act']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$img['Img']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Errors, if any? If not checking for them, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the obsolete `mysql_query` interface?

Comment: Sidenote: Your column `Start Time` by the way, contains a space. This is discouraged to use.

Comment: Look at your page source in the browser.  If you see PHP code then your web server isn't configured properly or you're not using it properly.  The PHP code should be evaluated server-side.

Comment: You are gonna need a space after `echo` in your data lines.

Comment: This `$employee` should be the variable to use, not `$id` etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251095/display-data-from-sql-database-into-php-html-table

Comment: just a comment, do not use mysql_* functions cf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna need a space after `echo` in your data lines.
Also your associative array is called `$employee`:

```
echo "<td>".$employee['ID']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$employee['Start Time']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$employee['Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$employee['Venue']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$employee['Act']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$employee['Img']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a whole whack of undefined variables. Since you're fetching your db results into `$employee`, shouldn't it be more like:

```
while ($employee=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
echo "<tr>";
echo"<td>".$employee['ID']."</td>";
            ^^^^^^^^^---note "new" var
echo"<td>".$employee['Start Time']."</td>";
            ^^^^^^^^^---note "new" var
```

?

Comment: Exactly, [just as I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998447/displaying-database-with-php#comment38867225_24998447) ;-)

Comment: Cheers for the response. You're right 
    while ($employee=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
should be 
    while ($gig=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){