# Making SQL query from php and showing to HTML

Tags: php, mysql

I tailored this page `mysql.php` but for the time being it appears blank-white on the browser.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> MySQL Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            $username = "username";
            $password = "pass";
            $hostname = "localhost";
            $dbname = "StudentLessons";

            //connection to the database
            $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname)
              or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
            echo "Connected to MySQL <br>";

            $query = "SELECT * FROM Teacher GROUP BY bathmida";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            echo "<table>"; // start table in html

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop through results
                echo "<tr><td>" . row['onoma'] . "</td><td>" . row['epitheto'] "</td><td>" . row['bathmida'] "</td></tr>"; //$row['index'] is a filed name
            }
            echo "</table>"; //close table

            mysql_close(); //close the db connection

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now I know for a fact that

1. The connection is legit.
2. The query is working because I tested them both.

I also advised another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251095/display-data-from-sql-database-into-php-html-table) here on [so] and it seems I am missing something important. The `<tr><td>` tags in HTML are set as they should be, so what might be the problem?

By the way, isn't there any other way to automate the process a bit? i.e. to develop a form that can support more queries etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add $ in below code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop through results
                echo "<tr><td>" . row['onoma'] . "</td><td>" . row['epitheto']     "</td><td>" . row['bathmida'] "</td></tr>"; //$row['index'] is a filed name
}
```

correct code is:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop through results
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['onoma'] . "</td><td>" . $row['epitheto'] "</td><td>" . $row['bathmida'] "</td></tr>"; //$row['index'] is a filed name
        }
```

Comment: by not putting $ its giving error but might be you have turn off error you need to put error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the page after <?php tag

Comment: OK i will add that to rly see what is happening because after adding the `$` it is still not showing anything

Comment: put error_reporting(E_ALL); after <?php tag so you will get the error if any

Comment: write print_r($result);exit; after this line $result = mysql_query($query);

Comment: once again nothing is printed

Comment: try this query directly on phpmyadmin SELECT * FROM Teacher GROUP BY bathmida and check your are getting data there ?

Comment: Please add ini_set('display_errors', 1); and error_reporting(~0); in the place of error_reporting(E_ALL); and check you must get error if any there

Comment: The query is ok. I also made the changes you suggested. Nothing showing yet

Comment: replace this $result = mysql_query($query); with $result = mysql_query($query,$dbhandle);

Comment: I did and I also added `$dbhandle` in the `mysql_close();` part too but nothing

Answer (score 0):

You miss $, and you must use like this : $row->onoma

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row->onoma . "</td><td>" . $row->epitheto"</td></tr>
```