# How to create a page automatically after pressing the Submit button (HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I enter information in a website then press the Submit button, the information is automatically saved in a database after that how the information display on a page?

Example: I entered my personal information in a website and saved it by pressing the submit button then I will see my profile page How did this happen?
and would I need to specify the action in the form if the page shows up when the end user submits the info?

like in StackOverflow site when we create an account automatically we have a URL and page contain our information

NOTE: I am a beginner in coding

Comment: This is a similar question that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251095/display-data-from-sql-database-into-php-html-table

Comment: You have to create a page where display the profile info by ID. You have no need to the specified page in action. After saving info in the database . Redirect page to profile page with last insert id .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display data from SQL database into php/ html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251095/display-data-from-sql-database-into-php-html-table)

Comment: so basically when submitting something its basically doing a POST call , when you want retrieve something you can use GET or POST. So you can read about the REST Architecture it will give you how the data is saving and retreving

Comment: You need to use database queries for saving and fetching. It is not always necessary that you have to use action in form you can submit the form without action too by using javascript, fetch api, ajax which is very good starting point for beginners.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply..and you mean I create  one page for the profiles and by the user id the information will change..please explain to me

Comment: Might I suggest a tutorial? This question is beyond the scope of a simple answer. Udemy has a free PHP + MySQL course - https://www.udemy.com/php-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: Also, please don't spam tags for the sake of it.

Comment: Ok, if I spam tags that because I need help if u don't know?

Comment: and thank u for the udemy link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your application should have at least two pages. Register.php and ViewProfile.php.

In first page, When user submits, all his information are posted to your Register.php and you can get them in your $_POST variable and you can do anything you like with them.eg: save in database.
Then after successful insertion , your script will get primery key of inserted record and redirect it to your ViewProfile.php page like:

```
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/ViewProfile.php?Userid=103"); 
exit();
```

Then ViewProfile.php can get userid from $_GET["Userid"] find the user in your database and show his information.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Answer (score -2):

You should make the form action be a PHP page where you take the $_REQUEST variables that you've submitted and enter them in the database using, for example mysqli [insert](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp), and then display the data using mysqli [select](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).  That is, assuming you are using a MySQL database to hold your submitted information.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.