# How to display data from an html form in an html table

Tags: php, html, sql

Please forgive me if this has been asked and answered before, but I couldn't find it in the search.

As stated in the title, I have a form built in HTML. I need the user inputted data to be displayed in an HTML table. I know the easiest way to accomplish this is probably to do so using SQL to store and then retrieve the data and PHP to output it in the table itself. For the life of me I cannot get this to actually work.  Google is absolutely my friend but literally nothing I've tried actually works. Examples would be wonderful and I seriously appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This link could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15251402/4149985

Basically, you need a web server, either locally or via a hosting provider with access to a database.

Your database needs to have a table, which contains records.

You need to use PHP to connect to the database, retrieve the records and then output them as a HTML table.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've read through the topic and have decided to use the function commented suggestion. I have an issue with that though, the table needs to be accessible to screen readers, so I need table heads for each
 column which are NOT contained in the sql data. How would I do so?

Comment: Hey Sarah, no problem! If you could mark my question as correct if it was right for you that would be great. With regards to your headings I'm assuming these are the actual table headers within table rows? You would make a table row in HTML by first adding `<thead>` after the `<table>` tag. Inside `<thead>` you want to make a new row by adding `<tr>` and inside the `<tr>` you want to add the heading: `<th>Heading Name</th>`.  Here's a fiddle so you can see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/mattclarke/hw9j4r0v/