# Print SQL Server tables to Website in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I want on my web page that has been created with WordPress to display tables from my SQL Server with the following query

```
select * from TopRank ORDER BY point DESC
```

Comment: You need to search for tutorials on the web. Here's a place where you want a fix for something. If you have tried something and couldn't get it to work, you **then** can post it here.

Comment: And also one thing before posting a new question, check if there are similar questions asked before, then post it. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251095/display-data-from-sql-database-into-php-html-table

Answer (score 0):

The following Query will display all the table in database. you just put the database name

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name' ORDER BY  TABLE_SCHEMA  DESC
```